# configure menu.xml file with uiform that i created custom

Tags: module

How can i configure menu.xml file with uiform that i created custom.

Here's the menu code:

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Test/Banners/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Test_Banners::first_level_demo"
             title="Shipping Vendor"
             module="Test_Banners"
             sortOrder="9999"
             resource="Magento_Backend::content" />



              <add id="Test_Banners::second_level_demo"
             title="Shipping Vendor Cost"
             module="Test_Banners"
             sortOrder="0"
             action="uiform/"
             parent="Test_Banners::first_level_demo"
             resource="Magento_Backend::content" />




    </menu>
</config>
```

Here's the routes file course:

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Test/Banners/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="uiform" frontName="uiform">
            <module name="Test_Banners"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

After Comment I updated My answer

Change action `action="uiform/Employee"`

and then magento will go to find Index.php file under

```
app/code/Test/Banners/Controller/Adminhtml/Employee/Index.php
```

create your `Index.php` file above directory and your controller code

Comment: for index.php i just created a folder and file like this:
public_html/testing2/app/code/Test/Banners/Controller/Adminhtml/Employee

<?php
namespace Test\Banners\Controller\Adminhtml\Employee;
 
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
 
class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
        return $resultPage;
    }
}

Comment: @jhonjhondoe check updated answer

Comment: still nothing show in that page
Page link:
http://testing2.dukaania.com/admin_1b9znn/uiform/Employee/index/key/50f3639350287831191a36a992b31481425b72247eef7edcf165004b8798c6a8/

Comment: @jhonjhondoe fire this command in magento root `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: still not find anything in that page :/

Comment: page is still blank

Comment: 404 error showing